# Groups with all maximal subgroups normal

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, maximal-subgroup

It is well-known that a finite group is nilpotent if and only if every maximal subgroup is normal. Furthermore every nilpotent group has all maximal subgroups normal.

**Question:**
Let $G$ be a group whose maximal subgroups are normal in $G$. If $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, then are all the maximal subgroups of $M$ normal in $M$?

Of course for finite groups this is true since any subgroup of a nilpotent group is nilpotent, so my question is really about non-finite groups.

**Edit 2015-11-05:**

In order to get some idea of whether or not this claim is true it would be very helpful to look at some examples of non-nilpotent groups (admitting maximal subgroups) in which every maximal subgroup is normal. If someone knows of relevant literature it would be appreciated.

Comment: your question: let $G$ is a group with all maximal subgroups normal; if $M$ is a maximal subgroup, then are all maximal subgroups of $M$ normal (in $M$ or $G$?). Please clarify to me.

Comment: @Groups Thank you for your comment. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry. Hypothesis is "$M$ is any maximal subgroup of $G$; all the maximal subgroups of ...... are normal in ......". Then is ........? (please, if possible, let me know these blanks; I want to know-I am not getting it.)

Comment: @Groups Is it clear now?

Comment: Great. Thats clear to me. Thanks very very much for effort.

Comment: Hypercentral groups (i.e. groups in which the upper central series hits $G$ at a possibly infinite ordinal) have that property, but they will not lead to counterexamples because subgroups of hypercentral groups are hypercentral.